# Scroll issue when scrolling fast, specially in responsive mode and on device

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, space

I can see this issue on Facebook and other sites, when in responsive mode. If you scroll fast enough, there seems to be a rendering/painting issue where it shows white space/flickering in some cases until the scroll slows down.

I can only think of slowing down the speed which I want to avoid.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: should this be reactjs and not angular? facebook's platform isn't in angular

Comment: I gave facebook for example, it happens no matter the technology used.